# Airflow: How to the pass the parameter transform_script with either as python function or python script in the S3FileTransformOperator

Tags: boto3, airflow

**Requirement:** Requirement is to download the s3 file and edit the file with logic and upload the file back to the same s3 location

**Logic**: Edit the file with the last row I need to remove the trailing delimiter and the double quotes, which I was able to achieve using python function

**Issue:** How can I either pass the python script or the python function to the operator `S3FileTransformOperator` and get the file updated? If not feasible with the `S3FileTransformOperator`, How can I achieve a function using boto3 in which I can download, edit and upload the file

**Python function:**

```
         # read the file into a list of lines
         lines = open(mys3file, 'r').readlines()
         lines[-1] = lines[-1].rstrip()
         fields = [field.replace('"', '') for field in lines[-1].split('|') if field]
         lines[-1] = '|'.join(fields)
         # now write the modified list back out to the file
         open(mys3file, 'w').writelines(lines)
```

**Code:**

```
import logging
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import pprint

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.s3_file_transform_operator import S3FileTransformOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

# Variables
tmpl_search_path = '/usr/local/airflow/dags/sql'
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

default_args = {
        'owner': 'business',
        'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 23),
        'provide_context': True,
}

# Define the DAG
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dag_A',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    template_searchpath=tmpl_search_path,
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
)

transform_file_over = S3FileTransformOperator(
    task_id='transform_file_over',
    source_s3_key='s3://mybucket/myfile',
    dest_s3_key='s3://mybucket/myfile',
    transform_script= #how to call the python function
)

transform_file_over
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The S3FileTransformOperator has an option transform_script which you can pass the location of the python script you want to use for file data transformation.

**Steps:**

1. Place your logic into a python file example,  **/tmp/scripts/transform.py** and copy the script file into your dags folder/a location which airflow worker can access the python script file.
2. Add execute permission on the python script file. **chmod +x transform.py**
3. Provide transform_script = "/tmp/scripts/transform.py" as an argument for the operator.

Refer here for detailed example : https://github.com/jamesang17/airflow-app/tree/master/airflow

Let me know your response !

Comment: Amazing example, Thanks Abdul

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, the shebang with the transform script helped me understand my issue.